# PHP get 4 months of dates using foreach

Tags: php, date

How would i get 4 months worth of dates from today using for each. I want to display the next 4 months of dates from today and format each one using foreach. Any ideas on how to do this.

Marvellous

Comment: where is the foreach getting the dates from, mysql database or an array or what?

Comment: please use the search function before asking. this has been answered before. It's also not hard to find out by looking at the php manual or by googling. you are supposed to do research before asking.

Comment: @Robin, You answered 12 times in SO, but there is one time voting you, and it is a down vote.. Is everything OK ?

Comment: @Soner Gonul - I am not quite sure. Obviously someone is not happy with my question but it matters not. A kind person has provided a fitting answer

Comment: the problem is you are creating duplication...

Comment: Here is my advice; More ask, more learn (_never stop learning_), more work, learn, learn and learn, then you can give nice answer in SO questions ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$ds = range(1,120);

foreach( $ds as $d){

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("today + $d day"));

}
```

This'll work if you are happy to guess that 4 months is 120 days away

Comment: THis will do. Its exactly what I was after. Simple and clear. Marvellous thanks.

Comment: @Robin: beware, 4 months away doesn't mean 120 days away. In fact the only case is when you run from January to April.

Comment: Slow, though, as you're forcing strtotime to do its parsing 120 times. Best to calculate the start/end dates ONCE, like tim fountain's answer above.

Comment: Agree, though could be faster using a Datetime object maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = time();
$endDate = strtotime('+4 months');

while ($date < $endDate) {
    echo date('j/n/Y', $date).'<br />';
    $date += 86400; // 1 day
}
```

Comment: date arithmetics do not consider DST. It doesnt matter in this particular case but in general, it should be avoided for more fitting functions, e.g. date_add, date_modify, strtotime, etc.

Comment: Yup fair point, so in this simple case perhaps `$date = mktime(12, 0, 0);` would be a little safer for the first line (midday today), just in case the script is run close to midnight.